# Weird behavior on SendMessage between Delphi 10.4 (sender) and Delphi 6 (receiver)

Tags: delphi, sendmessage

A weird thing happens when sending a string from a Delphi 10.4 app to a Delphi 6 app: only the first character is caught on the receiver.

I already found some other topics on the web about this issue, but I couldn't solve it.

Here's the code:

Sender - Delphi 10.4

```
procedure TfrmMain.sendMessageToApp(psValue: string);
var
  DataStruct: CopyDataStruct;
begin
  DataStruct.dwData := 0;
  DataStruct.cbData := SizeOf(PChar(psValue));
  DataStruct.lpData := PChar(psValue);

  SendMessage(
    FindWindow(nil, PChar(Self.psFormTitleERP)),
    WM_COPYDATA, Self.Handle, Integer(@DataStruct));

end;
```

Receiver - Delphi 6

```
procedure TForm1.WMCopyData(var Msg: TWMCopyData);
var
  psMessage: String;
begin
  psMessage := PChar(Msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData);
  ShowMessage(psMensagem);  
end;
```

One interesting thing I saw is a difference on `tagCOPYDATASTRUCT` between the two versions of Delphi: the `dwData` parameter is `DWORD` for Delphi 6, and `ULONG_PTR` for Delphi 10.4.

So... I have no idea what's wrong with these routines. Can anyone help me?

I think it could be some data conversion error, but I'm not so sure - I'm not used to manipulating bytes this deep.

Comment: This is wrong in so many ways. `SizeOf(PChar(psValue));` is the size of a pointer. You want length. `Integer(@DataStruct)` fails for 64 bit. Cast it to the correct type in the declaration of `SendMessage`. It's `LPARAM` isn't it? The sender sends UTF-16, the caller interprets it as ANSI. You assume the payload is zero terminated, but it may not be. Because, for instance, you get `cbData` wrong. Also you don't check return values. So `FindWindow` can fail.

Answer (score 6):

## Wrong size

First you should read the documentation for the [`WM_COPYDATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-copydata) message and the [`COPYDATASTRUCT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-copydatastruct) structure. According to the latter, the `cbData` member should be the number of bytes in the data pointed to by the `lpData` member.

You send `SizeOf(PChar(psValue))` which is `SizeOf(Pointer)` which is 4 or 8, depending on whether your app is 32-bit or 64-bit.

But you should instead send the length of the data, which is `(Length(psValue) + 1) * SizeOf(Char)`.

Before Delphi 2009, strings were ANSI (1 byte per char). In Delphi 2009 and later, strings are Unicode (2 bytes per char). So the factor to the right is either `1` or `2`.

The `+ 1` is because you probably also want to send the NULL character at the end of the string (assuming the string you want to send is not empty).

## 64-bit pointers

Further, in a 64-bit app (which your 10.4 app may or may not be), a pointer is 64 bit wide, so it won't fit in an `Integer` (still 32 bit). So in a 64-bit app, `Integer(@DataStruct)` is clearly wrong; you discard the upper 32 bits. It's like your phone number is 1234 5678 but you tell me that it is 0000 5678; I won't be able to call you.

You want `LPARAM(@DataStruct)`. (`NativeInt` and a few others will also work; the important thing is that you get right pointer size.)

## String types

Again, recall that strings became Unicode (2 bytes per char) in Delphi 2009.

So you send a Unicode string, but the receiver expects an ANSI string.

The simplest solution is to send an ANSI string. To do this, use `AnsiString` and `PAnsiChar` instead of `string` and `PChar`.

## Finding the right window

You really should verify that you actually have found the right window. If you don't find it, you likely want to handle that scenario in some appropriate way.

I'd personally match on both class name and window name, to make it a bit safer. Of course, there may be other windows with the same name on the end user's desktop. You may also want to consider the case when there are several (more than one) matching windows.

## At the receiver

At the receiver, `PChar(Msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData)` will work fine since we do have the terminating NULL character in the `lpData` buffer (or the pointer is `nil`).

It is also good practice to look at the `cbData` parameter to make sure that you don't read beyond the end of the buffer.

One possible solution is to use the `SetString` function:

```
SetString(psMessage, PChar(Msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData), Msg.CopyDataStruct.cbData - 1)
```

But if so, please first check that `lpData` isn't `nil` (why?).

(If you base the receiver's behaviour on `cbData`, you can also omit sending the NULL terminator in the first place. Clearly, there are many ways to do this, each with its own security implications. Really, we could write a book on this topic!)

Comment: Can't really support sending ANSI! At least send UTF8.

Comment: @David: But since the receiver is a Delphi 6 application, we are clearly in a legacy environment.

Comment: Also, you need to handle the lack of null terminator in the answer you have written. And receiver should look at `cbData`. I'd definitely send UTF-8 and then convert in the receiver.

Comment: @David: Yes, given the code of the receiver, the NULL is required.

Comment: Thank you, guys! As I said, I'm not used to work so deeply with bytes - I code ERP, in a high level programming & IDEs. It's not a commom case, for me, to do this kind of manipulating data.

Gonna make some changes in the code, guided by your comments, and then reply here!

Comment: Good afternoon, everybody!

Thank you so much, @Andreas Rejbrand! Your tips were awsome, solved my problem!

Closed case!